# Cant use flutter DateTime in ferry query

Tags: flutter, ferry

Here is the query

```
query UpcomingPendingEvents($attendantId: ID, $eventDateTimeGt: DateTime) {
    attendances(attendant_Id: $attendantId, attending: "0",
        event_Datetime_Gt: $eventDateTimeGt, first: 10,) {
        # some fields here
    }
}
```

I get the error `A value of type 'DateTime' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'GDateTimeBuilder?'` when I use the following query

```
gqlClient.request(GUpcomingPendingEventsReq(
            (b) => b
            ..vars.attendantId = attendantId
            ..vars.eventDateTimeGt = DateTime.parse('2021-12-15T17:00:00'),
    ));
```

And when I try to use it like that.

```
gqlClient.request(GUpcomingPendingEventsReq(
            (b) => b
            ..vars.attendantId = attendantId
            ..vars.eventDateTimeGt = DateTime.parse('2021-12-15T17:00:00') as GDateTimeBuilder?,
    ));
```

I get runtime error
`type 'DateTime' is not a subtype of type 'GDateTimeBuilder?' in type cast`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to assign it to the `value` on the `GDateTimeBuilder`.

```
 ...
 (b) => b
 ..vars.attendantId = attendantId
 ..vars.eventDateTimeGt.value = '2021-12-15T17:00:00' // <-- here
 ...
```